# How does a volcano for a science fair work?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry

In this video it shows me how to make a Volcano but what is the science behind it? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b_gltKtERY

Comment: If somebody wants to answer this, I'll spare you the "trouble" of watching the video - it's a baking soda + vinegar volcano.

Comment: This experiment is not to be confused with the ammonium dichromate vulcano experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The food color-dyed water is just there to add volume and color.

The household chemicals used are acetic acid (vinegar, $\ce{CH3COOH}$) and sodium bicarbonate (baking soda, $\ce{NaHCO3}$).

The acetic acid and sodium bicarbonate react to form carbon dioxide gas ($\ce{CO2}$), dissolved sodium acetate ($\ce{CH3COONa}$) and water ($\ce{H2O}$).  **It is the liberation of $\ce{CO2}$ gas that causes the foaming and bubbling**.

The chemical reaction is written as:

$$\ce{CH3COOH(l) + NaHCO3(s) -> CH3COO-(aq) + Na+(aq) + CO2(g) + H2O(l)}$$

Where:
l = liquid
s = solid
aq = aqueous (dissolved)
g = gas (vapor)